# Codebird search multiple terms

Tags: php, twitter, codebird

I want to know how to search multiple terms in codebird using the search_tweets method. Here is my code, I added OR in between every search term i wanted as it says in the Twitter Search API but it doesn't find any tweets

```
$params = array('q'=>'#producers OR Beatstars OR #Beatstars OR Instrumentals OR #Instrumentals OR #beattape OR Beattape OR Instrumental OR #Instrumental OR #myflashstore OR #soundclick OR Soundclick OR Send beats OR #beats OR FI Studio OR Hip hop beats OR Send beats to OR Pop beats OR Trap beats OR Beat store','lang'=>'en');    
$reply = (array) $cb->search_tweets($params);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add `'count'=> NUM`, like this:

```
$params = array( 'q'=>'#producers OR Beatstars', 'count'=> 20, 'lang'=>'en' );
$reply = ( array ) $cb->search_tweets( $params );
```

Comment: If required, you can return an object from your query directly, by setting this:  `$cb->setReturnFormat(CODEBIRD_RETURNFORMAT_ARRAY);`